# How is used the 'func' in data parameter of get in jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ive looked at the example of get in jquery website. The last example show this..

```
$.get("test.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
   function(data){
     alert(data.name); // John
     console.log(data.time); //  2pm
   }, "json");
```

I was wondering what is the "func" part..how it is used and what you can do with it ?

To me it seem of calling the function getnameAndTime somewhere but where ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means in php that the `$_GET` param will look like this:

```
$_GET = array (
   'func'  => 'getNameAndTime'
)
```

The second parameter in the `$.get` jQuery function is the data you are sending to the script.

Comment: How would look the php file ? that may help me understand.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. its a `get` parameter

Comment: Nah its okay i found what i want. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> To me it seem of calling the function
>   getnameAndTime somewhere but where

It's not explicitly calling the function 'getNameAndTime' but just a query parameter sent back to the server. 'func' is just the param they are looking for and I suspect the server page that they are hitting ('test.php') will know to call a function of that name.